# Cache folder for a library

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a canonic way to get some folder for a python library that can be used for a persistent cache (not a temporary dir). Something like `pkgutil.get_data`, but it should not be a directory inside the library package, supposing it can be optimized to zip and so on.

```
import pkgutil
CACHE_DIR = (pkgutil.get_data('my_library', 'cache') or b'').decode('utf-8')
# oups, zip_safe can be False
```

Comment: `~/.cache/*` is often used by Linux software. I'm not aware of Windows conventions, though